# I want to Upload a file and then I want to parse that file to get the phone number and email id to fill the the columns email and mobile

Tags: python, django, parsing, django-rest-framework, rest

I have created this model files to store a file two fields more fields.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False)
    mobile =  PhoneField(blank=False)
    resume =  models.FileField(upload_to='resume/')
```

and here is the view file.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser])
def upload_file(request, format=None):
    serializer =  ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

and with the help of this all i can do is that i have to provide all the three field which are there in the the model.py but i want just to upload the file and parse that file to get those two fields.
Suggest a way through which it can be achieved, I know it is something really basic but i cant figure it out.

here is the seriliazers.py file

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['email', 'mobile', 'resume']
```

Comment: https://pythoncircle.com/post/591/how-to-upload-and-process-the-excel-file-in-django/#:~:text=Here%20we%20are%20using%20openpyxl,the%20value%20in%20each%20cell.

Comment: The main problem is I just want to upload the file, and then want to fill the other two files based on that resume file, so first i need to send post request so that only file get uploaded and the other two fields remains empty, and when I will accomplished that task then i have parse that files and get mobile number and email id and then fill it in the those two empty left field. may be this is a very big task for me as beginner.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) (if file is pdf) and regex to extract email and mobile fields.